# How to return matrix?

Tags: c, matrix, parameters

I'm trying to make a Cramer-linear-solving, and I wrote a function that replaces a matrix column, just like that:

```
void replacecol(int c, int n, float mat_in[n][n], float vect_in[n],
        float mat_out[n][n])
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (j == c)
            {
                mat_out[i][j] = vect_in[j];
            }
            else
            {
                mat_out[i][j] = mat_in[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is currently void, and I want it to return the mat_out with it's values, when I call this function... How could I do that??

Comment: Why do you want to return it? What do you have to gain from it?

Comment: You can't return arrays in C. The function is already correctly set up

Comment: Well, you can't return arrays/matrices but you can return pointers.

Comment: If you want modify the matrix within the function, you can work with double pointers (**float)

Comment: Do you really want to return matrix? *mat_out[n][n]* would carry desired changes once function returns.

Comment: @Khronisos - What you just suggested will break the OP's already correct code

Comment: Or you could just give the function a pointer to the matrix as parameter so you don't have to return it.

Comment: @izlin `mat_out` already IS a pointer.

Comment: So, after many comments , it smell like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should clarify what you are trying to achieve with your code. The modification made on mat_out are already made on the passed matrix.

Comment: Alright, my teacher told me: "create a function to replace a matrix column, given a vector filled with desired new column values", and then he asked to create a Cramer's Rule program in C and make use of that already made replacecol(), then I want to call replacecol() when I need within my main() to solve the linear system

Comment: The code you shown does already what you need: matrix passed as `mat_out` parameter will be modified. What you can change is to use mat_in for the column modification. `mat_out` is quite useless.

Comment: But I want to call the replacecol() from the main(), and then continue working with the new values of the matrix (calculated within replacecol()), within my main() function... Then I think that I need some kinda return from replacecol()

Comment: take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid to use 2 matrices for your function. You can simply:

```
void replacecol(int c, int n, float mat_in[n][n], float vect_in[n]))
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mat_in[i][c] = vect_in[i];
    }
}
```

`float mat_in[n][c]` it is a pointer `float(*)[]` so modifications on that parameter are made on the passed matrix.

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know that the replacecol() would modificate the passed matrix itself... I thought it was like in Java, that is needed a return to achieve that... Thank you very much!!!

Comment: May the force of pointers be with you (and study something about them..) ;)